# Find right solution to include React + TypeScript at the same time in Laravel Mix webpack.mix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, laravel-mix

When i try to connect:

`mix.ts('resources/assets/js/app.ts', 'public/js/app.js')
   .react('resources/js/app.ts', 'public/js/app.js');`

There is mistake appears :

`Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.`

So, i resolve this like this:

```
`mix.react('resources/js/index.js', 'public/js/app.js')
.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    }, 
})`
```

But i'm not sure is it right, any suggestions ??? i'll be glad, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer but it might help for who has same problem.

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.ts('resources/js/index.tsx', 'public/js/app.js').react();
```

Put the following script tag before closing body tag in your Laravel blade template:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```